# How to debug/log 502 Bad Gateway from reverse proxy?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, reverse-proxy, debugging

We're running a web service and hitting 502 Bad Gateway randomly. The 502 is reported by reverse proxy (Apache 2.4.x) while talking to backend server (Apache 2.4.x). The problem randomly re-appears around once per 100,000 served requests so it's really hard to reproduce. I see that Apache allows configuring `ProxyBadHeader` directive where possible options are `IsError|Ignore|StartBody`. I have problems finding the exact cause of the error. I know that if I set `ProxyBadHeader` to `StartBody` the partial output would end up to the browser. I really would not want to emit the data to unknown end user so I need something better. **Is it possible to log all the partially received data from the bad gateway?**

The problem seems similar to [Apache bug 37770](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37770) but it should be fixed in the version we're running.

Comment: Usually this is due to the backend server taking too much time to return the reply. You can add the duration on your log files at both servers (%D) and check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, you are correct to point to [Apache bug 37770](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37770), which in the Apache's reverse proxy functionality. If you examine the patches cited there from 2008 until 2016, you'll see yourself that these are really workarounds. If the root cause disappeared in httpd-2.4, then this is not apparent neither from the conversation there or from the observed httpd behavior.

Either

```
SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1     # prevent a small percentage of 502 errors, comes with a performance penalty
```

or accept that a little percentage of requests get 502'd. Or migrate to haproxy.

I *guess* that if you did gather the backend's conversation, you would see that backend doesn't see the HTTP GET. This was result of my little investigation and I concluded that the connection gets somehow lost inside reverse proxy code (perhaps where backend connection is taken from pool or returned there).

Comment: We've since migrated to haproxy and all the random problems have disappeared. The haproxy configuration syntax is weird and I still don't get why they spell `let` as `acl` in the config but otherwise, haproxy is a *really* nice piece of software. Avoid versions 2.2.1 ... 2.2.4 because those suffer from bug that causes all uploads to randomly fail. See https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/790 for details.

Comment: /@MikkoRantalainen Good to see the final picture. I'm impressed to see you respond after 4 years; if more people followed up on such bugs to completion we would collectively have so much more nice things!

Comment: We tried using Citrix Netscaler as reverse proxy after Apache but that seemed buggy, too. The bugs in Citrix Netscaler are different from Apache reverse proxy bugs but some random bugs occur about at the same rate. Citrix Netscaler also had major problems with HTTP/2 so we had to use HTTP/1.1 only. This far haproxy has worked perfectly except the versions with upload bug I referenced above.